# RichFaces 4.5 - a4j:commandButton : oncomplete not triggered

Tags: richfaces, jboss7.x, jsf-2.2

After migrating from JSF 2.1 / RichFaces 4.3.0 to JSF 2.2 / RichFaces 4.5.17.Final, I noticed the oncomplete event was not caught anymore by my buttons of type a4j:commandButton. 
Server : JBoss EAP 7.0.2.Final

Here is a simple test page I made :

```
<h:body>

    <h:form id="testForm">
        <a4j:commandButton 
            id="doTest" 
            onclick="alert('onclick');"
            onbeforedomupdate="alert('onbeforedomupdate');"
            oncomplete="alert('oncomplete');"
            value="TEST"
            action="#{a4jCommandButtonTester.doSomething()}" execute="@this"
            render="@none" limitRender="true"
        />

        <a4j:log mode="popup" level="debug" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
```

Invoking that simple method :

```
@Named
public class A4jCommandButtonTester {

    public String doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Doing something");
        return "something";
    }

}
```

The result is :

- I can see the alert saying 'onclick'
- But I can't see alerts saying 'onbeforedomupdate' or 'oncomplete'
- While I see in the logs my bean method doSomething is invoked
- And I can also see the page gets the events oncomplete and onbeforedomupdate.

a4j:log results :

```
debug[12:16:56.266]: New request added to queue. Queue requestGroupingId changed to testForm:doTest
debug[12:16:56.266]: Queue will wait 0ms before submit
debug[12:16:56.268]: richfaces.queue: will submit request NOW
info [12:16:56.268]: Received 'begin' event from <input id=testForm:doTest ...>
info [12:16:56.304]: Received 'beforedomupdate' event from <input id=testForm:doTest ...>
debug[12:16:56.305]: Server returned responseText: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[256733305988132353:-1254866772301146127]]></update></changes></partial-response>
info [12:16:56.307]: Listing content of response changes element:
Element update for id=j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0
<update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[256733305988132353:-1254866772301146127]]></update>
debug[12:16:56.309]: richfaces.queue: ajax submit successfull
debug[12:16:56.309]: richfaces.queue: Nothing to submit
info [12:16:56.310]: Received 'success' event from <input id=testForm:doTest ...>
info [12:16:56.311]: Received 'complete' event from <input id=testForm:doTest ...>
```

My question : why are those events not caught by the a4j:commandButton ?
How to get this working ?

Remark :
If I put that :

```
<h:outputScript>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(document).on('ajaxcomplete', function(event) {
            alert('ajaxcomplete');
            console.log(event);
            console.log(event.target);
            console.log(event.currentTarget.activeElement);
        });
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

I get the event's target : it's the form...
And the event.currentTarget.activeElement is leading to the button... but I would find it tricky to use this information to build a 'workaround'.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the origin of the problem.

I'm using this phase listener from OmniFaces : org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener

But from what I read on OmniFaces's website, for the JSF 2.2 migration, I should have migrated from OmniFaces 1.x to 2.x (which I didn't) :

> OmniFaces 2.x requires Java 1.7, JSF 2.2, EL 2.2, Servlet 3.0, CDI
>   1.1, WS 1.1

I then update the version of the dependency to OmniFaces to 2.7, and it's working now, as a charm.